# how to find multiple occurence from mongodb collection with nested data

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have data with the following format:

```
{'user': 'A', 'books' :['One', 'Two','Three','Seven']}
{'user': 'B', 'books' :['Two', 'Four','Five']}
{'user': 'C', 'books' :['Five', 'One','Two','Nine','Ten','Twelve']}
{'user': 'D', 'books' :['One', 'Two','Six']}
```

The books that users have in common implies some form of collaboration 
between them. My goal is to find how  many books are being collaborated
on (or alternatively how may users are in some form of collaboration vs 
those that are not in any form of collaboration)

At this point im sure i cant  design a query that will reveal this information, so I'm wondering, is this something mongdb's mapreduce can do? And if so how?

I have not done any mapreduce before, but looking at the example on the mongodb docs it looks like there's a chance that its possible to do this with mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always prefer the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) over map reduce. It is much faster.
Your two problems are a bit different, first the books being collaborated on:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$books"},
    {$group: { _id:"$books", count: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}},
    {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
```

1. Unwind makes a document for each user and book in books
2. Grouping on books we sum the total of users collaborating
3. Filter out anything that didn't have a count of more than 1. No collaborators.
4. Sort in reverse just for fun

Will give output as:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "Two",
                    "count" : 4
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "One",
                    "count" : 3
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "Five",
                    "count" : 2
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Showing the books used more than once.

The users collaborating with others on books is a little more involved:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$books"},
    {$group: { _id:"$books", users: {$push: "$user"},count: {$sum: 1 }}},
    {$match:{count: {$gt: 1}}},
    {$unwind: "$users"},
    {$group: {_id: "$users", count: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
```

1. Unwind the books array just as before.
2. Group on the books again, but this time we push the users working on those books to an array.
3. Filter out anything that didn't have a count of more than 1. No collaborators.
4. Unwind the users array so we now have multiple book documents to a user
5. Group the users and sum up the books
6. Sort in reverse just for fun

has a result:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "C",
                    "count" : 3
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "A",
                    "count" : 2
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "D",
                    "count" : 2
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "B",
                    "count" : 2
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So this gives us the number of books being collaborated on for each user.
You can play with these more, alternating sorts and using $project to get nicer names on the keys, but I think this gives some concepts of how you can use the Aggregation Framework for these sort of problems.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using the [Aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

```
db.books.aggregate([
   {$unwind : "$books"},
   {$group : {_id : "$books", count : {$sum : 1}}},
   {$match : {count : {$gt : 1}}},
   {$group : {_id : "total", count : {$sum : 1}}}
])
```

This query counts the number of books which appear more than once in the collection, which is what you are looking for if I have understood correctly.

1. First operation unwinds or spread the books array
2. Second counts number of total appearances for each book
3. Third filters out books which appear just once
4. Fourth counts the total number of those books which appear more than once

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a grouping problem.

Whereas it can be solved with mapreduce, it can also easily be solved by using the aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

I would suggest something like the following (I can "translate" to pymongo if you wish):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$books" },  
    {$group:  {_id:"$books", usedby: {$sum : 1} } },
    {$sort: {"usedby": -1} }
])
```

it creates user-book pairs by $unwind, gives a count of how many users use each book, and then sorts them by descending order.